# How to get distinct paged list from SharpRepository FindAll method with selector?

Tags: sharp-repository

I was trying to get a field from an entitytype which has many dups using the sharprepository FindAll method with paging. I don't know how to supply the *Distinct* parameter or if it is even possible?

```
repo.FindAll(spec, c => c.Field, new PagingOptions<EntityType>(1, 20, "Field", false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point it's not something you can do, though it makes sense that we should add it to the list of things to add.  If you wouldn't mind adding that as an issue to GitHub I'm sure we can add it pretty easily.  We would just need to figure out the best way to include it.